# not able to copy tortoise svn tree info to the cilipboard so I caan paste it into MS Word

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am using the Repository Browser Torstoise SVN and I need to copy a whole tree of latest revision file name/revision/date/size information to MS Word. Is there an easy way to copy this information?

I can see this information and when I select and right click I am not seeing any copy to clipboard this information. There is just a copy URL to clipboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the svn command line [ls command](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.list.html) and pipe the results to a file this is super easy.

svn ls -Rv http://path.to.repo > output.txt

the 'R' argument is for recursive and the 'v' is verbose.